# How do I solve inequalities like $||x|-3|\geq0$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, absolute-value

As the title says, how do I solve inequalities like $||x|-3|\geq0$?

P.S. If the question seems invalid please correct me.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: How can $||x|-3|$ ever be less than $0$? $|\cdot|$ only outputs non-negative numbers.

Comment: I see, I have edited the post. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example is always true since the absolute value function outputs always non-negative numbers.

As a training example, consider $$||x|-3|=2.$$
When is it equal to $2$? When the argument of the absolute value is $2$ or $-2$.
$$|x|-2=2 \lor |x|-3=-2.$$
For the first equation move $-2$ to the right side. Then ask yourself: when is $|x|=4$? Now you should be able to answer that and then solve the other equation. The set of all possible values of x includes all of the deduced answers along the way.

For inequalities, to solve $|x| > a$ the argument must be greater than $a$ or smaller than $a$. To solve $|x|<a$ the argument must be smaller than $a$ and also greater than $-a$.